# Sort funtion: array with json values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to sort json obj :

```
const item = {
  usa: 100,
  israel: 972,
  italy: 200,
};
```

to an array like this :

```
[ { usa: 100},{ israel: 972}, {italy: 200}  ]
```

but I can't separate each object in the array in a function.

How can I deal with that?

Comment: _“but I can't separate each object in the array in a function”_ - what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Do you even really mean _sorting_ here? Doesn’t look like it.

Comment: my english is not very good sorry.

Comment: Have a look at [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and combine that with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I need to create an array, each item in the array has a key and value.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. I don't want to write code for you. I want to help you though if you have something you tried thus far

Comment: _“I need to create an array, each item in the array has a key and value.”_ - _that_ we could determine from the example you have shown already. That still does not explain where your _problem_ with this lies. What have you _tried_ so far, can you show us something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the use of [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (this will transform object into array of key-value pairs), [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and object's [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015)

Before `.map`, you could sort with the key

```js
const item = {
  usa: 100,
  israel: 972,
  italy: 200,
};

const res = Object.entries(item)
  .sort(([keyA], [keyB]) => keyA.localeCompare(keyB))
  .map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));

console.log(res);
```